# Store if user has pressed button at any point before

Tags: javascript, php, database, cookies, local-storage

I am making an image gallery, and I wish to have a vote up button people can press to increment the number of votes an image has received. Obviously I don't want people spamming the vote up button, so I want to limit each user to 1 vote up.

I do not have access to any kind of database (except writing to files), and a login system would not be good for my target audience.

What is the best way to store whether a user has visited the page before? Would it be better to use PHP or JavaScript or something else for this?

Comment: localStorage or cookies can easily be hacked. Also you need to store the combined score on your server, otherwise you cannot know how many people voted

Comment: Look into the many available and often free cloud storage services

Comment: If you are able to write files then you have access to the `sqlite3`. You can create an sqlite3 database it is only one file. Let us know if you wish to see how to accomplish this with this approach.

Comment: @Victory I will look into that, if I need any help I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an authentication system, you can limit the action of a user    temporarily, but the user can trick your system to vote multiple times.

Here are solutions not using a login/auth system (and their drawbacks) :

- You can store the upvote action client-side with cookies, localstorage or any other mean, but the user can clear all off that to regain the right to vote again. For most people it can be ok (depends on your audience), but any techy guy wanting to cheat the system will be able to do it.
- You can store the update action server-side with a reference such as the user-agent or the IP adress. But these "authentication" system are not reliable : user can share the same user-agent and change them easily. Several user can share the same IP adress and use proxy to change their IP adress.
- The third solution is to use an external system : a facebook +1 voting system (facebook uses its own auth system) or google+ or other external services. User won't be able to trick the system, but you don't own the upvote count on you side and someone without a facebook or google+ account will not be able to vote.

Comment: I feel like option 1 or 2 are probably my best bets. It's very unlikely that anybody in my target audience is going to try and cheat the system. With that in mind, would you recommend one more than the other?

Comment: The first solution is the simplest one. You just write a data client side. No ajax, no new storage system to develop. You can also combine solution 1+2 so that someone clearing its localstorage but not changing its IP can still be detected (note: usually people working in the same company share the same IP and only 1 of them will be able to vote in that case).

Comment: I am going to try and combine the two then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would go and find myself a database... but if you don’t want to use one, you can still write to a file. For example: Create an array and store the IP address of the user in it. Than write this array as JSON code to a file (json_encode) and store it. When a user clicks the like button, read the file, decode the json (json_decode) and check if the IP address exists in the file. If not: add to array and store to the file. The amount of likes, is equal to the amount of IP addresses in the JSON object.

The best way to implement this, is to make an ajax call when the like button is pressed. Than the visitor won’t see a page load.

Note: Technically you can set a cookie, to "remember" that the user already clicked the button. That would save you some reading of the file in which the likes are stored.

Comment: I thought about cookies, but I've had trouble checking if it exists or not. The only problem with your method is people's IPs changing, but I suppose that's just a problem you can't do anything about. Can you recommend any free database services? (I don't have access to the server)

Comment: search for "free mysql database hosting with remote access". The IP's might change, the only way you can change that is by requiring the user to be logged in on some account, like facebook or on your own site.